# Deeplearning4j: LSTM example for review sentiment analysis

Tags: java, deeplearning4j, nd4j

I am looking through the example of deeplearning 4j for classifying movie reviews according to their sentiment. 
[ReviewExample](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-0.4-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/examples/recurrent/word2vecsentiment/SentimentExampleIterator.java))

At line 124-142 the N-dimensional arrays are created and I am kind of unsure what is happening at these lines:

Line 132:

```
features.put(new INDArrayIndex[]{NDArrayIndex.point(i),
NDArrayIndex.all(), NDArrayIndex.point(j)}, vector);
```

I can image that `.point(x)` and `.point(j)` address the cell in the array, but what exactly does the `NDArrayIndex.all()` call do here?

While building the feature array is more or less ok what is happening there I get totally confused by the label mask and this `lastIdx` variable

Line 138 - 142

```
            int idx = (positive[i] ? 0 : 1);
            int lastIdx = Math.min(tokens.size(),maxLength);
            labels.putScalar(new int[]{i,idx,lastIdx-1},1.0);   //Set label: [0,1] for negative, [1,0] for positive
            labelsMask.putScalar(new int[]{i,lastIdx-1},1.0);   //Specify that an output exists at the final time step for this example
```

The label array itself is addressed by `i, idx` e.g. column/row that is set to 1.0 - but I don't really get how this time-step information fits in? Is this conventional that the last parameter has to mark the last entry?

Then why does the labelsMask use only `i` and not `i, idx` ?

Thanks for explanations or pointer that help to clarify some of my questions

Answer (score 0):

It's an index per dimension. All() is an indicator (use this whole dimension). See the nd4j user guide:
http://nd4j.org/userguide

As for the 1. That 1 is meant to be the class for the label there. It's  a text classification problem: Take the window from the text and word vectors and have the class be predicted from that.

As for the label mask: The prediction of a neural net happens at the end of a sequence. See:
http://deeplearning4j.org/usingrnns

Answer (score 0):

write a test and you will know it.

val features = Nd4j.zeros(2, 2, 3)
val toPut = Nd4j.ones(2)
features.put(Array[INDArrayIndex](NDArrayIndex.point(0), NDArrayIndex.all, NDArrayIndex.point(1)), toPut)

the result is 
[[[0.00,  1.00,  0.00],
  [0.00,  1.00,  0.00]],

[[0.00,  0.00,  0.00],
  [0.00,  0.00,  0.00]]]
it will put the 'toPut' vector to the features.